# Kassler vs Pork Shoulder vs butt

Tags: pork, pork-shoulder

I need to cook pork for a large party. Due to price and amount issues I would prefer cooking kassler (pork neck) but the recipes I found for pork discuss almost every other part of the pig except neck.

How much does kassler differ from a pork shoulder, for example? If I slow cook kassler like I'd slow cook a shoulder or any other part in given recipes, will it be inedible or disgusting?

Are there any pork preparations that are completely inappropriate for kassler?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! I've edited your question a bit to help with some clarity and I hope I've got your meaning correct. Please feel free to [edit] if I got anything wrong!

Comment: Are we talking about the cut or curing method? Kassler is cured, neck not necessarily so.

Comment: @Stephie I'm talking about neck. Sorry for mixing it up with kassler.